# Switch lighting of THREE.MeshPhongMaterial on / off dynamically

Tags: three.js

I wonder if there is a way to turn off the lighting from a MeshPhongMaterial on runtime.

I'm working on a scene with big distances between the meshes and because of this it's impossible to work with the implemented shadow of three.js.

So now I wanna try to turn off the light on a certain object, when it's behind another, which I'll determine by ray collision. In the next step it would be nice to ease in and out, instead of just switching the light off.

Any hints? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean lighting and not lightning.

Comment: @mat: what exactly is your idea by, turning off the light, do you want to make the object invisible when its behind some other object?

Comment: @shiva: No, I just wanna turn off a certain light source to be effected on an objects MeshPhongMaterial, when there is another object between the light source and this object. Currently all objects are effected by the light source, even if there are other objects between them, which are hiding the source of light.