# Three.js - Load a model with material that doesn't require a light source to be seen

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, 3d-model

I'm currently using Three.js, **version 71**. I first create my models using blender, and then I export them as a JSON file. I then use **THREE.JSONLoader** to load the models into my scene using the following:

```
this.jsonLoader.load(pathToModelFile, function(geometry, materials) {
  //...
});
```

The materials list only contains **THREE.MeshPhongMaterial** at index 0. This material seems to require a light source (like **THREE.SpotLight** for example) to be in my scene. Otherwise, my model will be black.

I basically just want to be able to load my models and not need to use a light source in order to see them. Therefore, I have the following questions, and answering any one of them would solve my problem:

1. Is there some flag or property in **THREE.MeshPhongMaterial** I could change that would allow my model to be seen without a light source?
2. If number 1 isn't possible, is there a way to use **THREE.JSONLoader** to give me a different kind of material that doesn't need a light source? For example, like **THREE.MeshBasicMaterial**?
3. Is there some way to export my models from blender that will already have the required flags/properties set (if possible)?

It sounds like I'm having the same problem that this guy mentions in the following link, but he never received an answer: [Switch lighting of THREE.MeshPhongMaterial on / off dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020566/switch-lighting-of-three-meshphongmaterial-on-off-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 dont know, think not

2 yes

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load(model, addthree1ToScene);

function addthree1ToScene( geometry, materials ) 
  {


  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(blahblah);


  three1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( three1 );
  console.log(three1);

 }
```

3 yes, in Blender you can set a material type on mesh before exporting, or you can edit material variables in the exported file

EDIT:
Or most stupid way, it is possible to edit Material in expoted Json File, via discussion to this answer.

Comment: For #2, that will remove the texture from the model. Is there a way to convert the THREE.MeshPhongMaterial to THREE.MeshBasicMaterial or any others? If not, is there a way to set my texture to THREE.MeshBasicMaterial or any others?

Comment: I think is not possible convert materials, only to replace.
You can definitely set Material in JSON file, in blender is it in material proportions in section THREE ...

Comment: Is it possible to take a screenshot of these options and put them under answer 3 in your post? Unfortunately I can't find these options in either of the THREE sections in blender (the one at the bottom-right when editing your model and the one on the left when you are about to export your JSON file).

Comment: I dont realize im using blender exporter for three js https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

Comment: Cool, so am I. Here is a screenshot of the settings: http://imgur.com/5vEKcwk. Do you know which one I use to change which kind of material I want to export?

Comment: Do you export any materials to your json file?

Comment: Yes. In the screenshot I showed you, I select **Face Materials**, **Materials**, and **Textures**.

Comment: Are you sure, you have materials exported in your json file?

Comment: Yes. When I export my model this way, the texture and materials are in the JSON file. However, I just noticed that **"shading": "phong"** is in the JSON file. Based on that, it seems like I should be able to change some sort of export option to get that to be something else. I really would want to avoid manually changing that.

Comment: After looking in the three.js source, it looks like the only other option is to have **"shading": "basic"**, which should give me exactly what I want.

Comment: Yes that is option 2 in my answer. I think new blender json exporter dont support basic or lambert materials, or i dont find them. Im start using wawefront objects http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

Comment: I just manually changed my JSON files to have **"shading": "basic"** instead, and that works. Looks like for now I have to edit auto-generated code, which I really don't think is a good idea, but like you said, it doesn't sound like there's any other way. Could you please edit your answer to include the choice to manually edit the JSON file to use **"shading": "basic"**? Then I can accept your answer.